# Adding date value to ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, date, date-parsing

From a web service I am getting a date value like "2011-05-31T00:00:00.000+03:00" and I want to add it into an arrayList(String). How can I parse it to String and write it like "31.05.2011" to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date date = df1.parse("2011-05-31T00:00:00.000+03:00")

DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String newDateString = df2.format(date);
```

Comment: you make something wrong, edit your question and add your code to add string to arraylist

Comment: ok I changed "SSSXXX" to "SSSZ" and worked but "newDataString" gets 30.05.2011 instead of 31.05.2011

Comment: I just have tried and new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"); returned newDateString = 31.05.2011

Comment: yeah that Z letter made difference now its working, thanks. Do you know why these Z, X letters change the output?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
public String getMydate(String mydate){
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
        Date date = sdf.parse(mydate);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);
        return sdf2.format(date);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

And check it with:

```
    String val = "2011-05-31T00:00:00.000+03:00";
    String res = getMydate(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` check the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html